# Problems with singletons when using component dependencies

Tags: java, dagger-2

I'm having a problem in understanding why the following code doesn't work.

I have following project structure:

```
@Component(modules = CCModule.class) 
public interface CComponent {
    XXX getXXX();
}
```

where

```
@Module
public class CCModule {

    @Provides @Singleton
    public XXX provide XXX(){
        return new XXX();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component(dependencies = CComponent.class, modules = AAModule.class) 
public interface AComponent {
    YYY getYYY();
}
```

where

```
class YYY {
   @Inject
   public YYY(XXX xxx) {
       ...
   }
}
```

I initialize everything as:

```
CComponent c_component = Dagger_CComponent.builder().cCModule(new CCModule()).build();

AComponent a_component = Dagger_AComponent.builder()
        .cComponent(c_component)
        .aAModule(new AAModule())
        .build();
```

Once compilation takes place i get the following error:

> Error:(11, 1) error:
>   com.test.CComponent (unscoped) may not
>   reference scoped bindings: @Provides @Singleton
>   com.test.XXX
>   com.test.CCModule.provideXXX()

What I'm aiming for is to have one component inherit bindings from other components to have the same references to an objects (singletons).

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You should put `@Singleton`to `CComponent` class declaration.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = CCModule.class) 
public interface CComponent {
    XXX getXXX();
}
```

Explanation is in error message: `CComponent` is unscoped, `@Singleton` is a scope. Dagger 2 does not allow unscoped components to use modules with scoped bindings.
However, now you will get the following error:

```
AComponent (unscoped) cannot depend on scoped components:
@Component(dependencies = CComponent.class, modules = AModule.class)
```

Unscoped components cannot have scoped dependencies. So you need to make `AComponent` scoped. To do this create custom `AScope` annotation.

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AScope {
}
```

And annotate with it `AComponent`:

```
@AScope
@Component(dependencies = CComponent.class, modules = AModule.class)
public interface AComponent {
}
```

These are new requirements appeared in latest [snapshot release](https://github.com/google/dagger/pull/96). It was discussed in corresponding [issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/107) and may still be changed.

Comment: @AlexanderVasiljev Tested on latest snapshot. Works fine =). Updated my answer a bit with custom `AScope` annotation. Something's not right with your code. Show it.

By the way, let's talk in english, this is not russian resource.

Comment: clean solution sir

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {NameModule.class})
public interface NameComponent {

}
```

for the component because dagger2 don't allow to use unscoped components with scoped modules

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the latest Dagger-2 release:
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/107