# Dagger2 Component (un-scoped) cannot depend on scoped components - Error

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am trying to compile https://github.com/svenjacobs/android-dagger2-example
but I am running into an error related to unscoped component depending on scoped components.  (Android Studio 1.1, Gradle 2.2.1).  Also if anyone knows of other Dagger2 Android examples WITH FRAGMENTS I would like to know about them.

UPDATE: Here is another example one very basic with fragments:
        https://github.com/gk5885/dagger-android-sample

```
/Users/Mac1/android-dagger2-example-master/app/src/main/java/com/svenjacobs/dagger2/ActivityComponent.java
Error:(15, 1) error: com.svenjacobs.dagger2.ActivityComponent (unscoped) cannot depend on scoped components:
@Singleton com.svenjacobs.dagger2.ApplicationComponent
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Here is the file ActivityComponent which is apparently not scoped:

```
import dagger.Component;

/**
 * Component for all activities.
 *
 * @author Sven Jacobs
 */
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class,
       modules = {
               MainActivityModule.class,
               AModule.class,
               BModule.class
       })
interface ActivityComponent extends AFragment.Injector, BFragment.Injector  {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);

    void inject(AnotherActivity activity);
}
```

And here is the scoped component:

```
package com.svenjacobs.dagger2;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Component;

/**
 * Application-wide dependencies.
 *
 * @author Sven Jacobs
 */
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
interface ApplicationComponent {

void inject(Dagger2Application application);

/**
 * Provides dependency for sub-components
 */
SomeApplicationDependency someApplicationDependency();
  }
```

Answer (score 16):

You need to provide a scope for the ApplicationComponent.  This doesn't necessarily have to be @Singleton, since Dagger 2 allows you to define your own scopes using the @Qualifier annotation on an interface.

```
@Scope
public @interface CustomScopeName {
}
```

You could then use it like so:

```
@CustomScopeName
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class,
   modules = {
           MainActivityModule.class,
           AModule.class,
           BModule.class
   }) .......
```

I think the reason you aren't allowed to use a scoped dependency in an unscoped component is to prevent Singletons from depending on non-Singleton objects and prevent cyclic dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Sometime during the development of Dagger 2.0 the behaviour was changed and scoping of components became more strict. See [this discussion](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/107). Because my sample projects relies on the SNAPSHOT release of Dagger 2.0 it broke.

As atamakosi said and which is also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170292/problems-with-singletons-when-using-component-dependencies) pretty well you need to add a custom scope to the `ActivityComponent`, for example `@PerActivity`.