# Subcomponent (unscoped) may not reference scoped bindings: @Singleton @Provides @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull

Tags: android, singleton, dagger-2, dagger

I am using dagger 2.11

Module

```
@Module
class MyModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideString() : String = "yo"
    @Provides @Named("injector")
    fun provideInzectorString() : String = "named_injection"

    @Singleton @Provides //The error goes away if I remove @Singleton
    fun provideRepository() = Repository(Interceptor(),"")
}
```

Activity binding module

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MyModule::class])
     abstract fun suggestionActivity() : SuggestionsActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MyModule::class])
    abstract fun editSubscriptionActivity() : SubscribeActivity
}
```

AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidInjectionModule.class,
        MyModule.class
})
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(MyApplication application);

        AppComponent build();
    }

    void inject(MyApplication app);
}
```

I get this error on compilation

```
SubscribeActivitySubcomponent (unscoped) may not reference scoped bindings:
      @Singleton @Provides @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
```

I have seen these solutions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46195553/component-unscoped-may-not-reference-scoped-bindings) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46195553/component-unscoped-may-not-reference-scoped-bindings?rq=1). Both ask you to annotate your appcomponent with `@Singleton` which I am already doing. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is `MyModule`'s scope(Application or singleton) is bigger than an activity scope.

```
 @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MyModule::class])
 abstract fun suggestionActivity() : SuggestionsActivity
```

Remove the two `(modules = [MyModule::class])`s or define activity specific modules.

You don't need `MyModule` here. It's redundant because it's already included in the `AppComponent`.